# Error parsing json created from a cfquery

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfml

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on with this.  Normally, I don't return data from a query via json, but I need to in this instance.

Here is the CFC function:

```
<cffunction name="f1" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" >
    <!---query goes here --->
    <cfreturn thequery>
</cffunction>
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{"COLUMNS":["C1"],"DATA":[["1"],["2"],["3"]]}
```

Normally, I would create a struct, and populate it with the data I want to return, and everything works fine.

I pass this back to the calling page, and use it as needed, but for whatever reason, I can't seem to get the json to parse correctly on the calling page.  I am getting `JSON.parse: unexpected character error`

jQuery:

```
$.post("myCFC.cfc",{method:"f1"},
    function(response){
        var data = $.parseJSON(response);
        //doing stuff here, but can't parse the json, so it doesn't matter
    },
    "json");
```

So, I figured I'd try just using the data, because I don't care about the column name in this particular case. That didn't work, so now I'm here.

Could someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `$.parseJSON` if you supply the json datatype. jQuery will do that for you automatically.

```
$.post("myCFC.cfc",{method:"f1"},
    function(data){
        //var data = $.parseJSON(response);
        //doing stuff here, but can't parse the json, so it doesn't matter
    },"json"); // <-- here is where you supplied the json datatype
```